# Email regex validator alternative for lookbehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, regex

I have this following code on my mvc application:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|" + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)" + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Upon searching, i saw that this is not working because of a lookbehind `((?<!...))`

Is there anyway that I can replace that lookbehind? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using javascript or C# ? Note that javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That is why i'm looking for an alternative. I need to validate email thru data annotation.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to validate the email address? [Read this first](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: [Stop validating email addresses with regex](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). If you absolutely positively *HAVE TO* use regex, take a look at [The Official Standard: RFC 2822](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: @Gerald Well it wasn't clear that you were trying to convert a C# regex to a JS one. Note that there are several questions on SO about an alternative to lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the following to validate the email:

```
try {
    var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(value);
    this.email = value;
}
catch {
    throw new Exception(); // or whatever
}
```

This is because the best (only with best results, none is perfect) email Regex looks like this:

`/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD`